# Increased tail latencies seen with redigo client library

Tags: go, redis, redigo

- Our service uses redigo as redis client library.
- Our application sees an rps of 4k.
- So for p99 requests the latencies are under the sla but for tail latencies we saw redis Get calls were taking more that 1 second.
- We checked server for slow queries but there were no slow    queries since all calls are just GET calls.
- We also saw cpu usage and memory usage **less than 50%**. Number of go routines were also normal.
- Library version we are using is v2.0.0 and at server we are using    redislabs.

**Pool configuration:**

> - Max active connections : 1000
> - Max idle connections: 200
> - Max Connection lifetime : 60 seconds.

**Can anybody help us understanding the root cause?**

Comment: It could be down to networking, graviton instances may be located in different parts of the datacenter or have different networking characteristics that lead to higher tail latency.

Comment: No this is not been seen with different services experiencing similar traffic.